# Jmeter's Dashboard with not initilaised variable

Tags: jmeter

I can’t understand why my dashboard contains not initialized variables.
I already verified all proprieties files but I can’t find the problem

Any help will be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your JMeter configuration got amended somehow in a way which prevents configuration properties values resolution by [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/), inspect *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries and modify the problematic properties in order to eliminate the errors.

First of all obtain fresh brand new copy of JMeter - let's start clean. Download the latest available release ([JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) as of now) from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and unpack it somewhere.

Once done go to "bin" folder of the unpacked archive and run sample test like:

```
jmeter -n -t ..\extras\Test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o foo
```

and open %JMETER_HOME%\foo\index.html in your favorite browser. If there you still see unresolved variables - something is wrong and you'd better raise an issue in [JMeter issue tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) providing full information about your environment, OS, Java, browser, etc.

If everything is fine - compare settings of "vanilla" JMeter and modified one and identify the differences.

More information:

- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for your advice